# Does CSS text-overflow: ellipsis work on Anchor tags?

Tags: css

Why does the following CSS not work?

```
a {
    width: 60px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It's because anchors are as standard, `inline` elements. Adding `display:inline-block` will make the above code work.

Comment: It must be: display: block instead of inline-block

Answer (score 10):

It's for box model, `display:block` will do the job

```
a {
    width: 60px;
    display:block;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}​
```

But it may cause you other problems to make the anchor(inline element) behave like box model element (display:block).

**Reference:** [**text-overflow**](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/textoverflow.html)

**Update:**

```
display:inline-block
```

[**Demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/2d3Bp/1/)

Comment: For some reason, `display: block` `list-item` actually works for me instead of `inline-block`.

Answer (score 1):

Add `display: block` to your css.